# CreateJS library - Touch event API is not supported at latest Chrome Update 79 version

Tags: javascript, touch-event, createjs

Actually we have developed a Touch event-oriented web-application using the CreateJS library.

These libraries to work in touch monitors, we need to enable touch API manually at the Chrome browser. So we have Enabled those flags in the older version.

But it's not working in the new version of Chrome - version 79. Because of Touch API in Chrome has been disappeared in the latest version.

We get another option to enable those Events in the latest version to set target properties at chrome  "--touch-events".

My real question is can we enable the touch event API, without making any manual property change in the Chrome browser. Our application is being viewed by many people across the globe. We cannot ask them to do this setup in their local chrome settings. It is very difficult for us to convince the users to make these changes in their local PC settings.

Our wish is to make the changes in the code level so that we no need to ask the users to configure their Chrome.

Do we have any alternative options to enable touch events API in code level without manual setup..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently fixed the same problem with our software.

If you're using the latest CreateJS.js you should be able to swap it with the one here which contains the fixes for touch:

https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/0.8.3-TOUCHFIX

Alternatively you can use this touch fixed version of createJS:

https://zimjs.org/cdn/1.2.3/createjs.js

If you're using an old minified EaselJS library moving to the newer createJS library could break your apps (as some functions have been deprecated). In this case your best bet is to copy the Touch.js class code out of the TOUCHFIX createJS library above and simply append it to the end of the Easel library you are using (effectivelly overwriting the old Touch.js class it contains).

This should fix things.

There's an indepth discussion of the issue here:
•   https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/997